# php session crossdomain not keeping session content but only session id

Tags: php, apache, session

So this has been asked a few times before, and my problem seems to be of a little different character.

Two domains:
x.y.com
z.y.com

I want to share sessions, so I do this on both sites:

```
session_name("shared");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.hojio.com'); <--- i have experiemented with many versions of this, nothing seems to change much
session_save_path("XX");
session_start();
```

When I do a print_r($_COOKIE) it gives me:
[shared] => gpppai72ukd0fnoesca08g5vk4

(on both sites)

So it has the same session_id across sites. But when i put a variable on one site, the other site will, on load, remove it from the session file.

Why is the information not kept, when it obviously looks into the same session file on the server?

I tried replicating on a windows localhost - and it works perfectly fine, apache on ubuntu. Not.

- Soren

Comment: I'm not 100% on this but even though you've called your sessions the same name and put the cookie in the same domain so that the cookie is available across both sites apache its self segments the actual server side sessions so when you create a session on site a when you instance it on site b it knows internally that they're different domains so creates a new session for site b with the same name as site a but obviously different values so what you have is 1 cross domain cookie and 2 server side sessions both with different values.

Comment: Hey Dave. I think thats entirely true. So what am I missing - its an apache configuration thing?

Comment: tbh I have no idea I've never done cross domain sessions like that when I need an SSO style system I use a pseudo session so instead of using a php internal $_SESSION I basically wrote my own class that uses a memcached as the session store and the cookie references the memcached object for that user to auto sign them in on site b.  I'm not entirely sure apache will allow you to use cross domain sessions as you want.

Comment: The great thing is that its working on my windows apache localhost - and not on the production apache ubuntu. Sigh.

Comment: In which case it could just be a permissions thing since windows has slack permissions perhaps apache on linux locks session files to a particular process ID or domain as a pseudo user a little like a PID.  And so site a's user process can't access site b's user process.  I am of course just guessing.  Perhaps the easiest way of you doing it would be to encrypt store all the login data required into a cookie and then just auto log them in when they visit the other site a little like how stackoverflow works! when you click login on the other sites it reads your cookie and logs you automatically

Comment: Actually thinking about it you've kinda answered me already. I only just realised.  it works because on your local host windows+apache you're accessing both sites with localhost/sitea localhost/siteb so the overall domain is just localhost and as such the session would be available for both sites no problems.  However on your live ubuntu server I'm guessing you have proper domain names assigned as such its 2 separate "instances" of apache and so you can't access the cross domain sessions.

Comment: To test add test.mydomain.com and test.domain2.com to your windows .htaccess file.  Edit your apache configs to support vhosts and setup a vhost for each domain so to access each site you go to the domain isntead of localhost/sitea localhost/siteb  I bet siteb wouldn't be able to access sitea's sessions then

Comment: Localhost domains are called a1.local.dk and a2.local.dk, so it's not the same domain

Comment: it is the same primary domain its just the subdomain changing both domains root are local.dk change one to local.com and then try it.

Comment: But isnt that the same as what im doing in my production value? The domain is both x.com

Comment: could be unix apache treats subdomains differently than windows apache probably tied back to the permissions so apache creates separate threads for each sub domain but because windows has slack permissions both subdomains can access each others session store where as on unix each sub domain cannot access each others session store.  Its got to be something specific to apache though and I know windows apache is "not quite right" in many ways due to the way windows works.

Comment: Do you might to store session in database with custom session handler, not in file? This solution will allow access to session data from different processes and even different physical machines.

Comment: Hey max, I would rather not make that dependency